# IsAuthenticated is always true even after Logout()

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, forms-authentication

I am trying to implement Form Authorization in my MVC application and for the most part it is working fine.However, when i trigger my Logout() method nothing happens. I have

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

on my homepage so i can see that it is still logged in afterwards.
Below is my logout method.

```
public ActionResult Logout(){
        TempData.Clear();

        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Abandon();

        HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
        cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);

        HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);

        HttpContext.User =new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

--- Edit ---

I have added the `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultA‌​uthenticationTypes.A‌​pplicationCookie);`

as was recommended by DGibbs, but the problem persists.

Comment: sorry, it was saying there was something wrong with the formatting, it is added now.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? I managed to replicate your issue using `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` however using: `AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);` did the trick for me.

Comment: my AuthenticationManager does't have any fucntions at all? :/

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Net` in your controller class?

Comment: And a reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;`?

Comment: I dont believe so, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Ahh sorry, my mistake its part of `Microsoft.Owin.Security`. You can just do: `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);`

Comment: Hmm now it says there are no definition for GetOwinContext(), btw thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i found the mistake.

If anyone else runs into this problem and they have tried what people said, try checking the properties of the project, apparently i had enabled WindowsAuth there and disabled AnonymousAuth, but once i switched those around its working like a charm.

[image]